# How can I repair a cracked porcelain undermount sink?

Tags: bathroom, sink

My bathroom sink is chipped and has a hairline crack in it. I've already attempted to fix it with a repair kit I purchased from Home Depot, but unfortunately, the damage is still visible.

This is a rental property, and I'll be moving out soon. I'm concerned that my landlord may deduct from my security deposit if the sink's current condition is considered 'damage' beyond normal wear and tear.

Here's a picture of the sink

[image: sink]

As you can see, the chip and crack are not severe but definitely noticeable.

Should I make another attempt to fix it or would it be more sensible to just replace the sink altogether? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, it looks more like a crack. I  dont think you can disguise it.

Comment: If you're dead set on attempting a repair then you could try filling and smoothing the crack as best as possible, then spraying the entire sink with an enamel sink & tub refinishing paint. No matter how good a job you do it'll still be obvious to anyone who looks though since the 'KOHLER' brand will be covered up.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that a chip and long cracks in a porcelan sink would be considered normal wear and tear so you'll probably be paying for replacement. Those sinks are under counter mounted and finding one that would fit would be hard. You might be able to order one from a plumbing supply store. Trying to fix it so it doesn't show will be almost impossible. If you can find one, replacing it yourself would be cheaper than having the landlord taking the cost out of your security deposit. If this is a multi-unit building, the landlord might have a few in storage.

Comment: Yep, looks like a new Kohler sink can be had under $150.  The trick will be finding one the right size.

Answer (score 0):

First, tell the landlord who may want a reasonable fee for the damage.  Up to $150 or so I would think it's easier for you to just pay it and walk away than to deal with it.

Otherwise ... undermount sinks start at $50.  If you're handy you can swap it yourself.  You may need another $10 of supplies.   Get a large piece of paper and trace an outline of the cutout in the counter, and take it to a few large hardware stores (who have cheap stuff) and a few plumbing supply stores (who may have customer returns, minor blemishes, etc in stock for cheap).  It should not be that hard to match the size.